Argument passing and dangling pointers
I know that, in general, when calling a function, the evaluation of the arguments of the function call can happen in any order, but I'm in doubt about this particular situation (imagine T has a move constructor that steals the object's internal resources):
void func(int result, T copied);

func(object.calc_something(), std::move(object));

In this case, std::move(object) involves two operations really, the casting to &&, which yields an xvalue if I'm not wrong, and which is a no-op really (it's an operation that disappears after compilation), and the construction of copied, which involves "stealing" the internal pointers of object.
So, could object in object.calc_something() be unsafe? In the sense that the internal resources of object have already been stolen at this point. That could happen if the construction of copied happens before object.calc_something(), which would make object unsafe to use.
In my understanding, parameter and argument are different things. The argument value is the value we are passing in (the xvalue), which can be caught in different ways depending on the type of the receiving parameter. What I'm asking is if the construction of the parameter itself belongs to what we call "argument evaluation".
I think it's not and so the construction of copied happens after all the arguments have been evaluated and hence object.calc_something() is safe.
Am I wrong or I'm misunderstanding something here? What does the standard say about this (I'm using C++17)?
This question is similar, but no one explicitly said if the construction of the function parameters themselves is part of the "evaluation" process of the arguments.

evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified. So you should split this code into multiple lines to avoid surprises.

There is no dangling pointer here. Especially when this is not a [mcve].

@FrançoisAndrieux I have fixed that sentence. And yes I wasn't convinced either by expressing it that way.

"could object in object.calc_something() be unsafe?..." At this point I think anything in C++ can be unsafe. You have to provide a mcve to be sure.

The issue here is that the call to object.calc_someting() could be done on the moved-from object; whether that's "safe" or not depends on what the move constructor for object does and on what "safe" means. And whether that produces a meaningful value also depends on what the move constructor for object does.

@PeteBecker "could be done on the moved-from object". Are you sure? Could object.calc_something() be executed after the move constructor of T has been executed?

The initialization of actual parameters from expressions is part of parameter evaluation and is therefore unsequenced. calc_something() may occur on a moved-from object.

In response to OP's edit re the proposed duplicate, from the 1st answer:  "...but the order of evaluation of function parameters is not guaranteed. std::move(a) MAY be evaluated first, or a.Something() MAY be evaluated first. What is guaranteed is only that both parameters will have been fully evaluated before f() is actually entered..."

@ABu -- that's the point; a "moved-from object" is what's left of the original object after a move-assignment or move-construction.

@Raymond Chen Turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it (that the execution of the move constructor of T can happen before the execution of calc_something() because the parameter initialization form part of the argument evaluation process. You can include the Pete Becker mention that a moved-from object refers to the object after the move constructor/assignment of the received object has been executed.

"could object in object.calc_something() be unsafe?" - Maybe, yes. "the internal resources of object have already been stolen at this point' - Maybe, yes. "That could happen if the construction of copied happens before object.calc_something()" - Yes. "parameter and argument are different things" - No. "[does] the construction of the parameter itself belongs to what we call "argument evaluation"" - Yes. "the construction of copied happens after all the arguments have been evaluated and hence object.calc_something() is safe" - No.

@RemyLebeau I thought argument is what you pass, and paramter is what is received. If a function receives an object of type U, but you pass an object of type T, where T has an implicit conversion operator to U, your argument has type T, the parameter a type U, and the parameter is constructed from the argument by using the conversion operator.

@ABu perhaps so: What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?, though many people just use the terms interchangeably.

expr.call (7): "The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter." (emphasis mine)

@RaymondChen Thank you; what's important regarding this question is initialization of a parameter. The part of "indeterminately sequenced" was never an issue. My confusion was that I strongly distinguish between argument and parameter, and I was focusing too much on argument as object whose type is the "decltype" of the expresion you write on the argument's position, and the construction of the parameter as if it were a different, later process, more similar to initializing a local variable "from" the value you obtained after evaluating the argument's expression.

Yes, I should have highlighted "the initialization of a parameter" in the citation, since that is the focus of your question. My mistake.
